How to write UI tests using XCUITest framework for large tableviews in UIKit app
I am trying to write a UI automation test for my iOS app using XCUITest framework.
My app has a screen with a UITableView that has a datasource which can have over 3000 rows.
My UI tests are getting stuck when trying to either find elements on this screen or even when trying to tap on buttons.
Example of usages:
app.cells.element(boundBy: 0).firstMatch.exists

or
app.buttons["FilterButton"].firstMatch.tap()

Upon inspecting the main app process, I notice the app is stuck in an really long process of iterating the whole 3000+ rows one by one and calling the tableView method:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt cellIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
Is there a way to avoid XCUITest to scanning the entire list of cells in the tableView?
Note: the firstMatch property is supposed to be used to avoid this long hiearchy queries, but this does not work when trying to use tap for example. As XCUI engine starts scanning the whole tableView trying to see if the button has no interrupting elements on top of it.

Perhaps you could fetch all the elements once, store them in a hashmap and then write a custom scrollTo and forceTap method that uses a gesture rather than a tap for the matching element in the map?

Fetching all elements is indeed what hangs the test. Well not the test itself, but the main app process which is scanning one by one each cell and returning the hierarchy data to the test process. I would think there has to be a way for XCUITest to avoid looping the whole tableView cells.

Ah so even a single fetch is causing a hang?  My thought when something like this occurs is I’m trying to test “too hard.” Either the tool isn’t right or I need test data as opposed to production.
